# MSMQ not all messages reaching remote server private queue

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I have been using same code for last 7-8 years, no changes to code or Remote message queue.

All of a sudden I am seeing that not all messages hitting remote server. And it's very inconsistent same message may work in 2 minutes and may time out next time.

I am using Visual studio 2019, windows 10 and noticing that randomly messages are not hitting queue server.

Comment: have you checked msmq logs? This could be caused by various reasons

Comment: Nothing in Even viewer for MSMQ

Comment: Express or transactional messages?
Any journaling enabled?